# Issue installing nbdime

Tags: github, merge-conflict-resolution

I need to install nbdime to fix a merge conflict in a jupyter notebook.

I ran the following command:

`pip install nbdime`

However, this failed while trying to uninstall a package called 'terminado':

```
Installing collected packages: terminado, gitdb, anyio, GitPython, argon2-cffi-bindings, argon2-cffi, jupyter-server, jupyter-server-mathjax, nbdime
  Attempting uninstall: terminado
    Found existing installation: terminado 0.8.2
ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'terminado'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.
```

Any thoughts on how to fix this, or avoid needing to uninstall terminado altogether?

TIA!